# SSIS query doesn't update in Execute Sql Task Editor but updates in sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

Here is the script:

```
DECLARE @Filename varchar(10)
SET @Filename = 'TubeSta_cycle_log.txt'

UPDATE    Torque.LastUpdate
SET       LastUpdated = getDate()
WHERE     Station  = substring(@Filename,1,CHARINDEX('_', @FileName)-1)
```

The 'Execute SQL Task Editor' executes with NO errors but doesn't update the table.

Comment: By chance do you have Transactions turned on in (Required) SSIS (default value is Supported) and then does a subsequent step error out? This would result in the Execute SQL Task rolling back the update.

Answer (score 0):

Well I see a few possible issues with this.

```
DECLARE @Filename varchar(10)
SET @Filename = 'TubeSta_cycle_log.txt'
```

The value added to the parameter is `TubeSta_cy` so your filename is being truncated.

If you run in SSMS:

```
select substring(@Filename,1,CHARINDEX('_', @FileName)-1)
```

The result is `TubeSta`, do you have a record with that value?

It seems like you need to expand your `varchar(50)`

Comment: made suggested changes and still same result: Changed varchar to 50

Comment: Other suggestion would be to create a parameter for the `GetDate()` to be used in the `UPDATE`.

Comment: if you look at the execution results for the package, does it show anything when you run the package?

Comment: I just created a test package that performs this update and it ran successfully. what other steps is your package running?